# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while reading from 2 textboxes

Tags: asp.net

```
   for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!((part)parts[i]).deleteUsed)
                ((part)parts[i]).hints = ((TextBox)partsView.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("textBox")).Text;
            ((part)parts[i]).PartsWaiting = ((TextBox)partsView.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("textBox1")).Text;
        }
```

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

Im getting this error for some reason, don't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: add break points and step through your loop and add quick watch on your textbox code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the rows will have 6 Cells?

Comment: ok!!thanks a lot..i will do that right away.
yes there are 6 cells in the row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is partly due to multiple chained deferences e.g.

```
a.getB().getC().getD()
```

and if one of those methods returns null, you can't easily identify what's going on.

Unless you're very sure of what you're doing, I would split the above into either:

1. separate lines and assign intermediate variables. A null will then become apparent wrt. the line that it's on
2. a set of functions that dereference and throw a `NullPtrException` upon resolving a null. Again, your offending line will become apparent immediately.

You'll note that the above isn't particular to your immediate problem. Rather it's a useful practise when you can't be sure that chaining methods won't return null at some stage.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that FindControl is not getting the TextBoxes. Set breakpoints and watch the `FindControl()`. Also make sure the IDs you are using ain FindControl are correct.

Comment: ok..i shall do that and im pretty much sure that the id#s are correct as well when it comes to the two different check boxes